# What is an Amazon Route53 "Alias" DNS record?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, alias, amazon-cloudfront

## AWS Route53 Alias value

Consider a domain registered on AWS Route53. HTTP requests to this domain should be served from a AWS CloudFront CDN distribution. In order to achieve this, an alias `A` record is defined:

[image]

## `dig` results

However, `dig` results shows actual IP addresses. In fact, these IP addresses are not constant and change over time:

```
# dig @1.1.1.1 serverlessdaystlv.io

...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       13.32.67.21
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       13.32.67.27
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       13.32.67.97
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       13.32.67.122
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       13.32.67.141
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       13.32.67.159
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       13.32.67.201
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       13.32.67.216

# dig @1.1.1.1 serverlessdaystlv.io

...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       52.222.232.13
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       52.222.232.24
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       52.222.232.43
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       52.222.232.55
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       52.222.232.63
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       52.222.232.104
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       52.222.232.136
serverlessdaystlv.io.   60      IN      A       52.222.232.224
```

## My question

**What is a Route53 Alias record? Is it a built-in type of a DNS record, or simply an internal AWS alias for the actual IP of the CloudFront distribution that is never exposed to the outside?**

Comment: Note that in the specific case of CloudFront, the answers to an Alias lookup not only change *over time* but also *over space* -- you're being provided with answers that Route 53 (on behalf of CloudFront) has determined are "optimal" based on where you are querying *from*, geographically.  Your answers all happen to be IP addresses of edge location servers in London.  I queried your domain just now, from the midwestern U.S., and my answers are IP addresses of servers in Atlanta, GA (US).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Route53 *alias records* is an own concept separate from DNS protocol [record types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types): e.g. `A` is an *address* record and `CNAME` is a *canonical name* record. `CNAME` is the one that acts like an alias pointing to the canonical name, while `A` has nothing to do with aliases. (See [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035).)

An *alias record* is an internal Amazon specific *pointer* working on a higher level; on technical DNS level it may result as an `A` or as a `CNAME`, depending on the situation. The DNS doesn't need to be aware of this internal pointer type nor target, as Route53 only answers with the resulting record.

An Amazon article [Choosing Between Alias and Non-Alias Records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) explains this in detail:

> *Alias records* provide a Route 53–specific extension to DNS
> functionality. Instead of an IP address or a domain name, an alias
> record contains a pointer to a CloudFront distribution, an Elastic
> Beanstalk environment, an ELB Classic, Application, or Network Load
> Balancer, an Amazon S3 bucket that is configured as a static website,
> or another Route 53 record in the same hosted zone. When Route 53
> receives a DNS query that matches the name and type in an alias
> record, Route 53 follows the pointer and responds with the applicable
> value:
>
> - **An alternate domain name for a CloudFront distribution** – Route 53    responds as if the query had asked for the CloudFront distribution by
>   using the CloudFront domain name, such as
>   `d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net`.
> - **An Elastic Beanstalk environment** – Route 53 responds to each request    with one or more IP addresses for the environment.
> - **An ELB load balancer** – Route 53 responds to each request with one or    more IP addresses for the load balancer.
> - **An Amazon S3 bucket that is configured as a static website** – Route 53    responds to each request with one IP address for the Amazon S3 bucket.
> - **Another Route 53 record in the same hosted zone** – Route 53 responds    as if the query had asked for the record that is
>   referenced by the pointer.

The confusion is understandable, as you seem to be adding an `A` type IPv4 *address record* while the *target* is a hostname instead of an IP address; something you would rather use with a `CNAME`!